# How to save credit card info using saved cc options?

Tags: magento-1.8, payment

I just enabled saved cc option for saving credit card numbers for customer login.
But its not saving. I have enabled that option.

Each time if I login as customer its asking to enter the card everything. What is the issue over here?What am I doing wrong.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save credit card data you have to be PCI DSS complaint. CE is not, so don't do it.

Comment: There is an excellent black market available for selling information on websites that store credit card data. They advertise quite frequently over on the unmoderated Magento Commerce forums. Something to think about if you've enabled saving CC info on a CE website. You're often not as secure as you think you are. It's hard for even the criminals to get crypto right.